# Problem with dual boot Windows - Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, kubuntu, boot-repair

I have installed Kubuntu over another distro in a system with dual boot Windows / Kubuntu , and now Kubuntu starts directly with no grub for dual boot.

I had to install it in EFI because installer warned me about that issue. I used Boot Repair and here is the Pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9S82qs2fd3/

Boot-Repair also says this when I Try to repair the grub:

> GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again. Alternatively, you can retry after activating the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option.

(not sure how to do that)

I have tried this: https://pastebin.com/artMiLjP

But it doesn't work.

If I use sudo os-prober into a Live Boot Repair console, appears:

```
/dev/sda1:Windows 10:Windows:chain
/dev/sdd3:Ubuntu 18.10 (18.10):Ubuntu:linux
/dev/sde1:Windows 10:Windows1:chain
```

But if I use it booting from my new Kubuntu, there is not output:

```
slamelov@Kubuntu-Ultra:~$ sudo os-prober
slamelov@Kubuntu-Ultra:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
# update-grub
```

or

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

# - it means Superuser

Comment: It does not work <br>

'Generando un fichero de configuración de grub...
Encontrada imagen de linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-13-generic
Encontrada imagen de memoria inicial: /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-13-generic
Encontrada imagen de linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-10-generic
Encontrada imagen de memoria inicial: /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-10-generic
Añadiendo menú de entrada de inicio para la configuración del firmware EFI
hecho'